# Filter strings with fixed number of digits

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I would like to subset a table where a string variable 'my_notes' contains exactly 10 digits phone number in MS SQL Server. I want something like

```
select * 
from mytable 
where my_notes like "%[0-9]{10, 10}%"
```

In standard regex I can use {10, 10} to specify min and max of the number of times of match. For example {10, 10} means I want to match [0-9] exactly 10 times. Somehow this does not work in SQL. What is the best way to write this kind of query?

Comment: SQL Server does not support Regex, only basic pattern matching.

Comment: As written the `%` will cause it to match strings with ***at least*** 10 digits (11 digits will also match, with the 11th being in the `%`). Is that intentional / acceptable?

Comment: REPLICATE('[0-9]', 10) is probably your best bet here.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
my_notes like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

However, @MatBailie is correct, that will match 10 consecutive digits, regardless of there being more digits around them. Since you want numbers of exactly 10 digits, I suppose you have to do:

```
my_notes like '%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%'
```

You probably also want to find records where the 10 digits appear at the very beginning or end of the string, so really it’ll be something even more ugly, such as:

```
(my_notes like '%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%'
    or my_notes like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%'
    or my_notes like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```